# Can't exclude subfolder from rewrite rules in Joomla

Tags: .htaccess-configuration

My website is made with Joomla. I've got a subfolder which contains plain html/css pages. I don't want Joomla to rewrite URLs inside this subfolder.
Now, I have the page in this path:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/myfolder/mypage.html
```

Joomla rewrite the URL in this way:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/en/myfolder/mypage.html
```

And the I get the message:

```
Article not found!
```

I'm not a pro with .htaccess configuration, but I've made a couple of tries. For example, I've but an .htaccess file in the subfolder with:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

And in the root .htaccess file I've added:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(demo_formati.*)$
```

But both of these operations are not the solution...
Any help? thank you.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a default behavior. mod_rewrite should not rewrite urls which are pointing to an existing file. Are u sure the url/path is right ?

Comment: See if you have a Joomla category called identical to 'myfolder'. If so, rename the category or the folder...

Answer (score 2):

First, the .htaccess should only do the rewrite, if the file or directory referenced is not found. So the most likely reason for this is that there is a typo in either the folder name or the directory name.

Second, if you can't find the typo **and** your site does is not configured to add .html to the urls, you can edit the line that checks file extensions and remove "html?|" from it.

Also, if you use custom error pages redirects to password protected folders will fail, if the defined **custom error page** returns a "not found" error. As far as the rewrite is concerned a 404 is a 404.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(foldername|foldername/.*)$
```

in your .htaccess file, replace "foldername" with your folder